# Static IP shared by multiple computers on a network

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have a network device which can be (manually) configured to send messages to a single IP address. On the same network I have a number of machines (ubuntu linux desktops, configured with static IPs 192.168.10.101 - 192.168.10.1XX), all of which can potentially handle these messages.

Is there a mechanism by which I can configure the device to send its messages to some IP like 192.168.10.254 and then have *any* of those other machines receive the messages? This is for the purposes of "high availability" and not load balancing, so I was hoping the answer would not be "add a machine at 192.168.10.254 and run HAProxy on it".

I presume I cannot have each of those boxes add an IP alias on 192.168.10.254 at the same time... I'm guessing this would cause weird network behavior/make the router mad?

Could I write an application which runs on each machine and pings 192.168.10.254 to see if any other machine is listening? And if not, then it would attempt to set up that IP alias? I imagine the typical distributed systems/race condition issues crop up here. Is there anything that already exists for this purpose and has decently solved this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you just want a floating IP. Heartbeat or ucarp (very simple) will do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own poor man's solution, but what you are looking for is (basic) cluster management. Check out [corosync](http://corosync.github.io/corosync/) and [heartbeat](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat).

If you decide to implement your own solution, I'd suggest *not* to use the same IP (no even after pinging the IP). It's not very good idea considering the ARP cache and possible IP collision. You may want to use the broadcast address, and let the nodes decide who will serve based on their IP, voting or other means.

Basically that's what those (and some other) cluster controller systems do, so I would use them instead.